# Does Commerce Kickstart distribution include "advanced search" capabilities?

Tags: commerce

By default the Commerce Kickstart distribution include a **Search block**. Just wondering if this distribution include a feature to add advanced search capabilities.

The advanced search would allow the user to filter by taxonomies terms.

Comment: Commerce Kickstart include only prepared commerce settings, no more...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Commerce kickstart includes the commerce search API module. http://drupal.org/project/commerce_search_api

Automatically created Search API db server, if none is found.
Auto-generated search index that includes all product display node types* and related product data.
Auto-generated facets for all node type categories and product attributes.
Optional integration with Search API Ranges (allowing for a price slider, for example).
Search API Filter class for product display node types* (allowing for an index composed only of product displays)
Facet API Filter class for removing facet items that do not change search results.
Facet API Filter class for hiding certain facets on the initial search (so that product attribute facets are only shown after the initial search, for example).

Comment: Exactly. All frontend views are powered by search api, and you get facets out of the box. Can't get more advanced than that.

(Note, that is Kickstart v2, not v1)

Comment: I understand, you are rigth. Facets search is much better thant the standar advanced search, it is just my client ask for the standar "advance search page" and I facets are kind of new.

Comment: Not sure what your definition of "standard advance search page" as this is open to interpretation. That being said, just create a view of product entities and some exposed filters for searching.